# Export data from Fetch to be available elsewhere in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax, fetch-api

Been trying to get my head around following issue. I have this code:

```
function display() {
  fetch('../data/data.json').then((response) => {
    response.json().then((obj) => {
      // need to export obj.data somehow from here to be available in other files
    })
  })
}
```

There is a button in my HTML, that fires this code, then I need to be able to retrieve data from promise and pass it to other file, so it can be imported there as a `variable` so `Handlebars` can render it to HTML.
I understand that is asynchronous operation, and I am mixing browser and node just dont get how to `module.exports` data from this case.. Please advise. Perhaps there is better way getting data from local .json and render it to HTML? Massive thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data using a singleton class to make it accessible.

**Singleton.js**

```
// To create the singleton behavior
let instance = null;

export default class Singleton {

  constructor() {
     if (instance) return instance;

     instance = this;

     return instance;
  }

  // To get the singleton object
  getInstance() {
     return instance || new Singleton();
  }

  storeVar(v) {
    this.v = v;
  }

  getVar() {
    return this.v;
  }
}
```

**Display.js**

```
import Singleton from 'Singleton.js';

function display() {
  fetch('../data/data.json').then((response) => {
    response.json().then((obj) => {
      // need to export obj.data somehow from here to be available in other files
      Singleton.getInstance().setVar(obj);
    })
  })
}
```

---

**PS: storeVar and getVar can be removed because of this.v is public anyway. I putted it here so you can understand how it works.**

Answer (score 0):

You can export the `Promise` object returned by the `fetch` and import it in the file that will use the resolved response. Like this,

```
export function display() {
  return fetch('../data/data.json').then(response => response.json());
}
```

This will export the function from the current file. Now, when we need to use the resolved response in other file, import it first

```
import { display } from '<relative_file_path_of_display_function>';
```

Then, you can resolve the `Promise` returned from `display()` function like,

```
display().then(jsonData => {
    // use the value here (referenced by `jsonData`)
})
```

You can render the template in the block above and pass the resolved data